# File permissions unset or incorrect

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible `copy` module to copy a file. The linter tells me "File permissions unset or incorrect" and I don't understand the problem.

Here is the ansible task

```yaml
- name: Ensure some.txt is there
  copy:
    src: some.txt
    dest: "{{ some_path }}/some.txt"
    force: false
    mode: '644'
```

Where `some.txt` is a file that exists in the `ansible/files` directory.
I have also tried with `mode: 0644` but no luck.

My ansible version:

```sh
$ ansible-lint --version
ansible-lint 5.0.7 using ansible 2.10.8
```

Restarting the editor fixed it, but that's not really an answer.
Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you try again corerctly with `mode: 0644` because it is definitely the correct value to use => https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameter-mode

Comment: Change `0` to lowercase `o` for octal `o644` permission

Answer (score 3):

You just need to specify `mode: 0644` in your playbook and it will be all good.

Comment: I did try that, as described in my question. That was not the issue.

Answer (score 2):

risky-file-permissions
File permissions unset or incorrect

Missing or unsupported mode parameter can cause unexpected file permissions based on version of Ansible being used. Be explicit, like mode: 0644 to avoid hitting this rule. Special preserve value is accepted only by copy, template modules. See https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/71200

Reference: https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/default_rules.html

If you're using some module who requires the usage of mode... Set the mode and the error will vanish.

Comment: Sorry I don‘t understand your answer. Didn‘t I use the mode parameter correctly?